# Java back-end and JavaScript front-end, how to join?

Tags: java, javascript, html, client-server

I'm new to creating a web application with a Java back-end and a JavaScript, HTML 5 front-end. How do I pass content between the two?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a web framework.  These will integrate all three technologies you mention into a server and fully functioning webapp.  You will also need to be working with JavaEE.

I recommend [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or [Play](http://www.playframework.com/)

Look up some tutorials on how to get started but basically these frameworks will create the server backend that launches on a port and can host different sockets etc... and since theyre in Java the backend code can literally be written anywhere in the project...front end is easy too, you'll see how it works once you work through your first tutorial with them :)

Answer (score 0):

[Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) is what you need indeed.

Answer (score 0):

on a back end you add end points, and on front end you hit those end points w/ ajax